# What's wrong with these words?

Tags: pronunciation

I've been reading and while pronouncing, again, the word "**tomb**" noticed that there's no adequate answer to why it should be pronounced the way it is. So I've looked up for why we don't pronounce "**b**" and why it doesn't read as "**tom**" and found a few more words that have similar problems.

- **Tomb** - *[tuːm]* (Where is the double 'o'?)
- **Climb** - *[klʌɪm]*
- **Comb** - *[kəʊm]*

Comment: What kind of answer would be satisfying to you? To me, acceptance that English spelling and pronunciation have a tenuous and unpredictable relationship at best is the most universal and permanently satisfying answer.

Comment: From The Guardian [What is the origin of the silent 'b' at the end of English words such as lamb, comb, crumb and bomb?](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,,-1417,00.html) ***climb** was Old English **climban**, and **bomb** comes from Italian **bomba.** The b-sound was lost by about 1300. It leaves traces to the present day, however, in pairs such as **climb-clamber, crumb-crumble. Thumb** appears to be a rogue case, because here the 'b' is not etymological...*

Comment: Spelling is just a calcified convention. Before spelling was normalized, the word had a variety of spellings: *tomb(e),  toumb(e), toume, tumb(e), tumba, and thombe*, reflecting a combination of scribal idiosyncracies and regional pronunciations.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88760/why-tomb-is-pronounced-the-way-it-is/88923#88923